# Android hide AppBarLayout when i scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android

this below xml is my simple layout which i try to hide `AppBarLayout` when i scrolling `RecyclerView` but it doesnt work and i cant fix that, in `CoordinatorLayout` i have two children as `Toolbar` and `AppBarLayout` and i put toolbar inside that, hiding `AppBarLayout` doesnt work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sample.ActivityMain">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper_ntb_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bg_ntb_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#4527A0"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:shadowColor="#22000000"
                        android:shadowDx="3"
                        android:shadowDy="3"
                        android:shadowRadius="1"
                        android:text="{fa-search}"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="25sp"/>

                    <com.gigamole.library.NavigationTabBar
                        android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_round_circle"
                        app:ntb_active_color="#4527A0"
                        app:ntb_animation_duration="150"
                        app:ntb_corners_radius="50dp"
                        app:ntb_inactive_color="#dddfec"
                        app:ntb_preview_colors="@array/red_wine"/>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_megaphone"
        app:layout_behavior="com.sample.Configurations.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: so where is the recyclerview in the xml you posted?

Comment: @Lino `recyclerview` is on `ViewPager`

Comment: I think should be something like `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` on the Toolbar